# how to fix "error: unexpected element <view> found in <manifest>"

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio 3.3

File > Save All; Sync with File System; Sync Project with Gradle Files
Build > Clean Project
Run > Debug app

```
error: unexpected element <view> found in <manifest>
```

Android resource linking failed
...\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:

```
error: unexpected element <view> found in <manifest>
```

AndroidManifest.xml contains view:

```
    <view android:name=".ZAreaView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent">
    </view>
```

failure to build and display of view -- android SDK 28.6
build.gradle: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
I can remove view from the manifest and compile but then view will not show.

successful build and display of view -- android SDK 23.3
build.gradle: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

Comment: IF you want to add a custom view, the normal syntax is <fullyqualifiedname.ZAreaView>.  Also, view isn't a tag (View is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove view from Manifest.xml

```
<view android:name=".ZAreaView"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent">
</view>
```

add ZAreaView to new layout puzzle.xml
 
recommended by vilpe89 and Gabe Sechan

```
<com.modelsw.SixPuzzles.ZAreaView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

add into the java class Puzzle under onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.puzzle);
```

Error inflating class com.modelsw.SixPuzzles.ZAreaView

modify puzzle.xml from

```
com.modelsw.SixPuzzles.ZAreaView
```

to

```
View
```

error in style

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent"
```

changed to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"
```

final configuration for layout puzzle.xml

```
<View
    android:name=".ZAreaView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
</View>
```

success
maybe the style error was the reason I got the inflating class error
but View works
I credit vilpe89 and Gabe Sechan for getting me started.

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidManifest.xml doesn't allow a view tag inside of it.

I'm assuming you want to display an activity that contains this ZAreaView or the ZAreaView might be the activity.
In this case what you would do is to replace the  tag with an  tag

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using wrong element in your AndroidManifest.

Correct way to declare an Activity is using [activity element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element).

So try this:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".ZAreaView"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent">
</activity>
```

OR if you try to show custom view which you created (extends View), then add it to your Activity's or Fragment's layout xml:

```
<com.yourpackagename.ZAreaView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you left it in the wrong place.
Ensure you have to push it in the application tab.

```
<application android:label=".Android">
    <view android:name=".ZAreaView"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent">
    </view>
</application>
```

Comment: That is where it was originally exactly as you suggested. I am sorry it was not obvious in my original question.